# Match at exact 3 character in a word length of 4 with all possible combinations

Tags: regex

In the following word list

```
ABCD
AAAA
AAAD
AAAB
BBDA
CCCC
CCCA
DADA
BABC

...
all possible 256 combinations
```

Using regrex, I want to select words which has my pattern, A or B in any combination covering exact 3 position out of 4.

Expected output:

```
AAAD
BBDA
BABC
```

I know using **[AB]{4}** I can match whole world but conditional search with exact 3 position out of 4 creating confusion.

Comment: I feel like a non-regex solution would be easier. Also, why isn't things like `BBBD` in the output? I feel like the expected output is missing a lot of entries...

Comment: Why `264` combinations? Shouldn't it be `256`?

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed BBBD will be there in output but I am only showing the output from enlisted inputs. The 4 letter word are made up of A, B, C and D so the possible input would be 4^4 = 256. Thanks

Comment: Corrected @Toto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rephrasing and confirming the rules of matching you said so my solution is adhering to it,

- three positions out of four should be occupied by either `A` and `B`
- Only one position goes reserved for `C` or `D`

If this is correct, you can use this regex to match the strings you want.

```
^(?=[AB]*[CD][AB]*$).{4}$
```

**Explanation of above regex:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=[AB]*[CD][AB]*$)` - Positive look ahead to ensure either `C` or `D` appears only once in the string so other three positions are occupied by `A`s and `B`s
- `.{4}$` - Capture four letters `A` to `D` using dot as they are already validated to be `A` to `D` by positive look ahead.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1FQsK/4)**

Here is a **[regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3D%5BAB%5D*%5BCD%5D%5BAB%5D*%24).%7B4%7D%24)** for better visualization

[image]

**Edit:**
Detailed explanation of `(?=[AB]*[CD][AB]*$)`

A [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is written as `(?=some regex)` and contrary to normal regex matching and consumption, a lookaround (positive/negative lookahead/lookbehind) just matches the characters and does not consume them, meaning as soon as the lookaround expression is over, the regex marker is reset back to where it was before the lookround began matching. In this regex we have `[AB]*[CD][AB]*$` as expression inside it, where `[AB]*` means it will match any character in the set (`A` or `B`) zero or more times followed by `[CD]` which means it needs to match exactly one character (as there is no quantifier here) from char set which is either `C` or `D` and further again `[AB]*` matches any character `A` or `B` zero or more times and finally ensures end of string is reached as it has `$`.

In summary, logical meaning of this expression is, that there will be exactly one occurrence of either `C` or `D` while it can be surrounded by `A`s or `B` on either side as needed to form four alphabets matching all combinations of four letters having only one occurrence of `C` or `D`.

Also, incorporated suggestion by [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo) where `[A-D]` can be changed to just `.` Many thanks to Revo.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Corrected. First lookahead by mistake was not correct. Fixed and updated. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Then my assumptions are not correct I listed above. I need to update them. Just few moments :)

Comment: Ok, my assumptions were not correct where I assumed at least one `A` and at least one `B` should appear but as OP wants any three positions to be filled by either `A` or `B`, the regex actually gets much simpler. Updated my post. Check now.

Comment: Very nice solution +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks buddy and thanks again for helping me correct my regex as I assumed the post incorrectly initially.

Comment: Amazing explanation. I have problem in understanding the second part of your explanation; (?=[AB]*[CD][AB]*$) . Is it possible to break this part, it will help others newbies to understand it better.

Comment: The `[A-D]{4}` regex could be `.{4}`. Saving a few keystrokes `^(?=[AB]*[CD][AB]*$).{4}$`

Comment: @kashiff007: Sure, let me add a detailed explanation of that positive look ahead in my post.

Comment: @revo: Yes you're right. As the look ahead already checks all the validations of letters, `[A-D]` can be changed to `.` Good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @kashiff007: I've tried adding a good detailed explanation of that positive lookahead. However, if my explanation still misses something, please feel free to again ask anything anytime.

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
^([^AB][AB]{3}|[AB][^AB][AB]{2}|[AB]{2}[^AB][AB]|[AB]{3}[^AB])$
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to match all the strings that have exactly three characters that are either `A` or `B`. This implies that the string will have exactly one character that is not `A` or `B`.

You can do this by replacing all the As and Bs in the string, and checking if the remaining string is only one character:

```
for string in all_your_strings:
    if len(re.sub(r"[AB]", "", string)) == 1:
        # match!
    else:
        # not match
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex:

```
^([^AB\r\n]*[AB]){3}(?!(?1)).*$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/i1Bakm/1)

If recursions (`(?1)` cluster) aren't supported in the engine you are working with go with this instead:

```
^(?:[^AB\r\n]*[AB]){3}(?![^AB\r\n]*[AB]).*$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/i1Bakm/2)